# Nativescript Splash Screen takes more than 15 seconds to load

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I see Nativescript takes a lot of time in a startup . For 15 seconds, the splash screen is visible and then the app loads. I read somewhere that building the app in release mode will cause the difference in start time , but is causing no difference.

I tried configuring Webpack too as per the doc but it is getting failed and I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

## prepare"

Comment: I have seen a lot of chatter lately about using webpack to help with angular load times https://docs.nativescript.org/best-practices/bundling-with-webpack

Comment: @RandyJohnson I tried webpack , but the build is getting failed with the error  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
# prepare

Comment: You can use https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries App for reference purpose this has webpack in action.